# How to access a variable in mysql database from another class?

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I am trying to access a variable from one class in another.

In my example below, I have 2 files, one called `login.java` and `usermainpage.java`.

I want to access a variable called `sessionId` that is in `login.java` from `usermainpage` class file.

I tried several methods but it is not working at all, in login class file, I declared `sessionId` as a `public string` and in the file I define it as equals to a data that I retrieved from my database. (If you see the code I am doing a database connection also).

I thought by returning sessionId at the end of the function I can now access this variable from all other java files but no, in my `usermainpage.java` file, I tried printing out `sessionId` and it displays nothing. Let me know of a solution, thank you.

```
// login.java file
public class login extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    public String sessionId;
    Connection con;
    PreparedStatement pst;
    ResultSet rs;

    private String LoginButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        try{
            String query = "SELECT * FROM `accounts` WHERE username=? and password=?";
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/restock", "root", "password");
            pst = con.prepareStatement(query);
            pst.setString(1, txtUsername.getText());
            pst.setString(2, txtPassword.getText());
            rs = pst.executeQuery();
            if(rs.next()){
                String userType = rs.getString("usertype");
                sessionId = rs.getString("id");
                System.out.print("##########" + sessionId + "##########"); //this prints out the id I want
                if(userType.equals("Admin")){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Login is successful as admin");
                    mainpage admin = new mainpage();
                    admin.setVisible(true);
                    dispose();
                } else{
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Login is successful as user");
                    usermainpage user = new usermainpage();
                    user.setVisible(true);
                    dispose();
                }
            }
            else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Incorrect username or password");
                txtUsername.setText("");
                txtPassword.setText("");
            }
            
        } catch(HeadlessException | SQLException ex){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, ex.getMessage());
        }
        
        return sessionId;
        
    }

}

//usermainpage.java file
public class usermainpage extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private void RequestButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
          String type = txttype.getSelectedItem().toString();
          String name = txtname.getText();
          String quantity = txtquantity.getText();
          String status = "Pending";
          String userId;
        
          //Create new class object from login.java
          login testing = new login();
          userId = testing.sessionId;
          System.out.print("########## " + userId + "########## "); //this prints out null value
     }
}
```

EDIT: These are some of the problems I encountered based on the suggestions.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Follow the [Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html).

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Hi is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

There are so many problems with your code:

1. You should always follow [Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html) e.g. you should name your class as `Login` instead of `login`. Similarly, the name of your method should be `loginButtonActionPerformed` instead of `LoginButtonActionPerformed`.
2. I do not see any use of the parameter, `java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt` in your method, `LoginButtonActionPerformed`. I would remove it from its definition and the calls.
3. You should avoid making variables `public`. You should keep `sessionId` as `private` or `protected` [as per the requirement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) and create the `public` accessor and mutator for it as shown below:

   ```
   private String sessionId;

   public setSessionId(String sessionId) {
       this.sessionId = sessionId;
   }

   public String getSessionId() {
       return sessionId;
   }
   ```
4. You are returning the value of `sessionId` from the method, `LoginButtonActionPerformed` and therefore you need to call this method inside your method, `RequestButtonActionPerformed` as follows:

   ```
   login testing = new login();
   userId = testing.LoginButtonActionPerformed(evt);
   ```

   However, for this, you need to declare your method, `LoginButtonActionPerformed` as `public`.
5. A better approach would be to declare `LoginButtonActionPerformed` as `public void` and then you can do:

   ```
   login testing = new login();
   testing.LoginButtonActionPerformed(evt);
   userId = testing.getSessionId();
   ```

Comment: I just declared the LoginButton function as public, on the other java class file I did "userId = testing.LoginButtonActionPerformed(evt);" as you said but there is an error, the suggestions are create local variable evt, or create parameter evt and create a field evt all options which still return null for me

Comment: I also cannot remove the action evt in my login function because I am using this "LoginButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                LoginButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });"

Comment: The signature, `RequestButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)` has already a parameter with the name, `evt`. So, you are just passing this `evt` to `LoginButtonActionPerformed` which shouldn't be a problem. Can you edit your question with all the suggestions in the answer? It will take you 5 minutes but save you a lot of effort to deal with the problems. I'll wait for your update.

Comment: I can clearly see the problem. You are calling `LoginButtonActionPerformed` from `DisplayRecords` where there is no `java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt`. That's why I asked you to declare `LoginButtonActionPerformed` as `void` (Check point#5 in the answer). After that, in the `DisplayRecords` method you can do `login testing = new login(); String userId = testing.getSessionId();`.

Comment: I understand sir, but after trying your solution it is still null, let me show u picture of what I wrote

Comment: Well, the problem is that until `LoginButtonActionPerformed` is called from somewhere, the value from the database can not be assigned to `sessionId`. How are you calling `RequestButtonActionPerformed`? If you can invoke `RequestButtonActionPerformed`, the method `LoginButtonActionPerformed` will be invoked from itside it and your problem will be solved. Also, why you have declared `RequestButtonActionPerformed` as `private`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219516/discussion-between-jackson-etherchain-stake-and-arvind-kumar-avinash).

Comment: @JacksonEtherchainStake - I hope the solution worked for you. Do not forget to mark the answer as accepted so that future visitors can also use the solution confidently.